# How can I check if function is a partial?

Tags: clojure, partial, currying

Is there a possibility to check if something is a partial function in Clojure?

It would be best to have something like `(partial? (partial + 10))` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious: why do you need that?

Comment: @Yehonathan I am implementing Shen in Clojure and there I need to differ between normal functions, and partial functions. (Due to design decisions).

Comment: What is Shen? Also, what about anonymous function created via `#()`?

Comment: @Yehonathan http://www.shenlanguage.org/

Comment: I'm curious too. Why would a program have to behave differently whether it's given `inc`, `(partial + 1)` or `#(+ 1 %)`?

Comment: Its because of my implementation. Shen has a dual namespace system. Therefore a symbol can represent a function and a value at the same time. But every symbol evaluates to itself. This is why there is the function "function" which receives the function of the symbol. But when using currying there is no symbol behind covering the function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, because functions created by partial are just "normal" functions.
You could however use some metadata for it, like this:

```
(defn partial2 [f & more]
  (with-meta (apply partial f more) {:partial true}))

(def partial-plus (partial2 + 1 2))

(meta partial-plus) ;;=> {:partial true}
```

Haven't really thought through the consequences of this approach though...

Kotarak came up with a nicer solution that works, but not always. For example take this:

```
(partial? (partial + 1)) ;;=> true
(partial? (partial + 1 2)) ;;=> false
```

This works:

```
(defn partial? [f]
  (let [[fst snd] (-> (class f) (.getName) (string/split #"\$"))]
    (= ["clojure.core" "partial"] [fst snd])))
```

with string/split being the split function from clojure.string (1.3) or clojure.contrib.str-utils2 (1.2).

Comment: clojure.string is in 1.2 as well.

Comment: You should probably test also for `clojure.core`, not only `partial`.

Answer (score 5):

You can with a hack.

```
user=> (let [partial-classes (map class [(partial + 1)
                                         (partial + 1 2)
                                         (partial + 1 2 3)
                                         (partial + 1 2 3 4)])]
         (defn partial?
           [x]
           (some #(instance? % x) partial-classes)))
#'user/partial?
user=> (partial? (partial - 1))
true
user=> (partial? (partial - 1 2))
true
user=> (partial? (partial - 1 2 3))
true
user=> (partial? (apply partial - 1 2 [3 4 5]))
true
```

*EDIT:* Fixed according to Michiel's comment. That you have to know the innards of `partial` confirms the hacky nature.

Answer (score 2):

Functions created by partial are just normal functions, but if you are hell-bent on it, maybe something like this could help? :

```
(defn partial?
  [f]
  (clojure.contrib.string/substring? "partial" (str (class f))))
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if something like this is fool-proof.